# Residuals and fitted values using fit function

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, exponential

I am using the `fit` function in MATLAB and am having some issues retrieving fitted values.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but we should have

```
y = y_bar + residuals
```

for any observations.

When using MATLAB's `fit` function such as,

```
[cfun, gof,outputs] = fit(x,y,'exp2');
```

I would be under the impression that I could retrieve fitted values with

```
fittedvals = y - outputs.residuals
```

However, if I try to reproduce the results by calculating the function with

```
[cfun, gof,outputs] = fit(x,y,'exp2');
param = coeffvalues(cfun);
fitted = param(1)*exp(param(2)*x)+param(3)*exp(param(4)*x);
```

The results vastly differ.  More specifically, the values obtained in fitted seem to be the result of

```
fittedvals = y+outputs.residuals
```

Also, if I fit using a `poly5` model, the fitted values obtained by doing the difference between observed values and residuals seem to match values obtained by the long form equation.

Comment: You may use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/feval.html) function if you want to eval the line fit on other points. If you want to calculate the function on new points manually, you may read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cfit.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about cfit or feval.  Works for me!